# How often do Apple update fixes for Safari on iOS?

Tags: browser, safari, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I have the same VH units bug that many struggle with on safari. I understand that their are workarounds but when should we expect a fix? I don't want to pay them $100 just to join their developer forums either. I find it frustrating when these types of bugs are left unfixed in a live environment for such a long time.